# How add null inputs while files are uploading, and then this files set to input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

e.g. I should upload 3 files. and  when I click "upload" should to appear 3 input. and when files finished to upload they  will write into this input.
I add file in a loop. and while files are uploading user should see preloader

```
onSubmit(e: any) {
this.alertService.clearMessage();

for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
  this.fileUploadService.upload(this.files).subscribe(data => {
    if (!data) {
      this.alertService.error("Select files");
    }
    else {
      this.newRow.push(" ");
      this.filesList.push(data);
      this.alertService.success("File url is: " + data.url);
    }
  }, error => {
    this.alertService.error(error._body);
  });
}
```

and my html

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of filesList; let i=index" >
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" *ngIf="file.url" value="{{ file.url}}" /></td>
      <td>{{ file.size/1024 | round }} Kb</td>
      <td>{{ file.modified * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }} </td> 
      <td>
        <img *ngIf="deleting == i" src="data:image/gif;"/>
        <a *ngIf="deleting !== i"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" (click)="onRemove(i)"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it.

```
onSubmit(e: any) {
this.alertService.clearMessage();

for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
// Im getting empty fields by this way and know the number of uploaded files
  let newItemId = this.filesList.push(this.fake) - 1; 

  this.fileUploadService.upload(this.files).subscribe(data => {
    if (!data) {
      this.alertService.error("Select files");
    }
    else {
      //  push data in array of getting lenght
      this.filesList[newItemId] = data;
      this.alertService.success("File url is: " + data.url);
    }
  }, error => {
    this.alertService.error(error._body);
  });
}
```

}